# Event records which occur today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a `Event`'s model with attributes `starts_at` and `ends_at`. How can I find records for events which are occuring today. Events are said to be occuring today if the todays date is either on or between `starts_at` and `ends_at` of events. `starts_at` and `ends_at` are `datetime`'s. I did not see the need to add any code of model, I can if some one asks for it.

Comment: I didn't get understand, why the downvotes? I am looking for a solution in rails. Don't know why is it broad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Please comment if there is any other better optimized solution.

```
Event.where('starts_at<= ? AND ends_at >= ?', DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
scope :today, -> { where(starts_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day) }
```

That should return all of your events that have a `starts_at` time between the beginning and end of the day.